# Nest.js websocket setuup

Tags: websocket, nestjs

Does someone have a working sample for integrating nestjs with websockets ?
I tried this setup and injecting the EventGateway to my app module as a provider

```
@WebSocketGateway({ path: '/api', namespace: 'events' })
export class EventGateway {
  @SubscribeMessage('events')
  findAll(socket: any, data: any): Observable<WsResponse<number>> {
    return from([1, 2, 3]).pipe(
      map((item) => ({ event: 'events', data: item })),
    );
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('identity')
  async identity(socket: any, data: number): Promise<number> {
    return data;
  }
}
```

I tried connecting to it through the browser using

`let ws= new WebSocket('wss://localhost/api')`  but it failed unfortunatly.

Comment: Are you using the websocket adapter or socket.io (socket.io is default and if you don't set an adapter is what will be used )

Comment: Just websocket.. would you please provide an article to read on how to do this adapter setup to use websockets instead of socket.io?

Comment: [From the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/adapter#ws-library)

Comment: it's still refusing the connection after adding this line `app.useWebSocketAdapter(new WsAdapter(app));` I've removed the namespace as it was not supported by the `WsAdapter` and tried removing the path and the same issue presisted

Comment: Try `ws://` instead of `wss://` and properly add the `port` to the URL of the `new WebSocket()` call

Comment: it works now thanks so much, please make the docs as an answer to the question so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using the `new WebSocket` approach the [websocket adapter](https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/adapter#ws-library) should be used instead of the default `socket.io` adapter. Also, the `ws://` protocol should be used unless a secure connection is set up, and the port should be specified to be the same as the port of the HTTP server